# The process cannot access the file 'C:\FolderStructure\APP\pic.jpg' because it is being used by another process. asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ioexception

Below code, which browses/attaches a document and sends it through email, when executed returns IOexception.

```
if (inpAttachment1.PostedFile != null)
{
   HttpPostedFile attFile = inpAttachment1.PostedFile;
   int attachFileLength = attFile.ContentLength;
   if (attachFileLength > 0)
   {
       strFileName = Path.GetFileName(inpAttachment1.PostedFile.FileName);
       inpAttachment1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strFileName));
       Attachment attach = new Attachment(Server.MapPath(strFileName));
       mail.Attachments.Add(attach);
       attach1 = strFileName;
    }
 }

 objClient.Send(mail);

 if (attach1 != null)
   File.Delete(Server.MapPath(attach1));
```

I get the IOexception on below line of code.

inpAttachment1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strFileName));

What is wrong with it?

Comment: It looks like you are using DevExpress.Web `PostedFile` object to save the file. DevEx recommends using `UploadedFile.SaveAs()` instead (possibly because of this problem). 
Also, your code shows you are saving to disk on one line, and reading that file on the next. This sometimes causes a FileIO exception.  You could maybe put a ThreadSleep(10) to let it sleep, but the sleep time will vary by filesize and disk throughput.

Comment: This worked. Thank you.